# NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath returning NO always in device not in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have programmed an app following the standford course on iOS - Core Data Lesson. My app works perfectly on the simulator but on the device is causing problems, `[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:` is always returning NO, causing the app to enter `SAveFORcreating` always, after a while it becomes slow and doesnt load the data from core data anymore. This doesn't happen in the simulator. So please some help!

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (!self.recipiesDatabase) {  
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        self.fileurl = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"RecipiesDatabase"];
        NSLog(@"URL IN FILE %@", url);
        self.recipiesDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:self.fileurl]; // setter will create this for us on disk
    }
}

- (void)useDocument
{


    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.recipiesDatabase.fileURL path] ]) {
        // does not exist on disk, so create it
        [self.recipiesDatabase saveToURL:self.recipiesDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            NSLog(@"No existe");
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
            [self fetchFlickrDataIntoDocument:self.recipiesDatabase];

        }];
    } else if (self.recipiesDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        // exists on disk, but we need to open it
        [self.recipiesDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            NSLog(@"OPen");
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
            //[self fetchFlickrDataIntoDocument:self.recipiesDatabase];

        }];
    } else if (self.recipiesDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
        // already open and ready to use
        NSLog(@"Normal");
        [self setupFetchedResultsController];

    }
}
```

Comment: Try deleting app from simulator and test it again, i'm guessing you'll get `fileExistsAtPat`h as `NO` on first run.

Comment: Not really, I have runed the app in 2 different devices actually many times because first I didnt know what was the problem. But thanks! :)

Comment: If its a first start i'm guessing it'll always have `fileExistsAtPath` as `NO`. Because you are checking for the file in `NSDocumentsDirectory`, on the first run there will be no file in that path. You usually overwrite that file path from bundle file or from somewhere else.

Comment: This happens to me usually when I forget that device is case sensitive while simulator is not.

Comment: Why are you creating the file in a block? You shouldn't do this asynchronously, it's possible to hit `fileExistsAtPath` before the file has been created if you do it like that. Device is slower than simulator for some operations.

Comment: Sorry Im new how can I make it asynchronously? If you can re-type the code would be great

Comment: I solved this issue, it was something related to the url string. Thanks for the tips

Comment: In my case it gives me NO at both device and simulator. I used FileManager to check url.path...